# How to do an if statement in a Django template to find if a decimal value is 0

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Basically, I want to find out if a decimal field value is 0.00. Then, I want to output a different value in the template. See code below. The code does not work.

```
variable = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

#template

```
{% for item in table %}
{% if item.variable is 0.00 %}
      <li><strong>Total: </strong> Unknown </li>
{% else %}
      <li><strong>Total:</strong> ${{ item.variable }}</li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This does not work. It outputs: Total: $0.00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this with `if not item.variable` for example, since `0.00` has truthiness `False`. This condition will also check if the value is `None` (so `NULL` in the database), which is probably something you should consider as well:

```
{% for item in table %}
    {% if not item.variable %}
        <li><strong>Total: </strong> Unknown </li>
    {% else %}
        <li><strong>Total:</strong> ${{ item.variable }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you only want to check for zero, you can check it with `== 0`:

```
{% for item in table %}
    {% if item.variable == 0 %}
        <li><strong>Total: </strong> Unknown </li>
    {% else %}
        <li><strong>Total:</strong> ${{ item.variable }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I just tried this and regardless the value - it outputs Unknown. Thank you, your second answer worked.

Comment: @NateP: then it looks like `variable` is a string? Can you inspect in your view what the type of `item.variable` is (iterate over the `table`, and `print(type(item.variable))`.